# How to make custom Tiles in android google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Android's Google Maps api v2 provides a TileOverlay to which TileProviders can be added. A TileProvider will generate a Tile object given the lat, long, and depth. In order to make a tile, one must give it width (easy), height (easy), and an image represented as a byte array (confusing me). If I wanted to 'draw' a simple object and then turn it into a byte array, how would I do this?

For instance I am looking for something that looks like

```
Canvas canvas = new canvas();
...
canvas.drawRect(); //Or something like this (just an example)
...
byte[] bytes = canvas.SomeConversionFunctionOrProcessThatIDontKnow();
return new Tile(1,1,bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public byte[] getByteArray (String image) throws IOException {
 File yourImg = new File(image);
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(yourImg);
 WritableRaster wRaster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
 DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) wRaster.getDataBuffer();

 return data.getData();
}
```

This should do the trick ; )

Comment: Is there a way to draw an image manually (using drawOval, drawRect type functions) and then convert it to a byte[]?

Comment: When you use Graphics in Java, do you save the result into a BufferedImage? If you do so, you should try the same code, starting with "WritableRaster" and try. I don't really have a better solution ;)

Comment: So to be clear, I create a new BufferedImage, obtain a Graphics object from it, then use the Graphics' functions such as drawRect(), etc to form the image, and then use bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getData() to obtain a byte array?
Thanks!

Comment: That's the approach, but to make things clear, I do not know if it will work. O: ). Tell me if it does, and if not, we'll try to find another solution.

Comment: This won't do the trick. `Android.getAvailableLibs().equals(JavaSE.getAvailableLibs())` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

`Tile#data` should be compressed image data in one of the [supported image formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).  In other words, the raw contents of an image file.  If you already have a decoded `Bitmap`, use [Bitmap#compress(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to write it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then get the `byte[]` from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(TILE_DIMENSION, TILE_DIMENSION,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
......
//draw something
......
Tile tile = convertBitmap(bitmap);
bitmap.recycle();
return tile;
}

private Tile convertBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bitmapData = stream.toByteArray();

    return new Tile(TILE_DIMENSION, TILE_DIMENSION, bitmapData);
}
```